# C/C++ underlying representation of char, unsigned char and signed char

Tags: c++, c, char, undefined-behavior, integer-overflow

Would I be correct to say that the underlying object representation (bit pattern) in each of the following definitions is the same?

```
char c = 240;
unsigned char c = 240;
signed char c = 240;
```

So, the *signed*-ness matters only when `c` is used in an expression (or casts)?

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if the `char` and `signed char` ones have undefined behavior.

Comment: @melpomene, I'm pretty sure the signed overflow rule applies to initial values as well. In the case of `char`, it depends on the implementation as to whether it's signed or not.

Comment: Your answer is there - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8385824/bytewise-reading-of-memory-signed-char-vs-unsigned-char

Comment: @chris: Signed overflow causes undefined behavior only for arithmetic operations. Assignment/initialization (i.e. overflowing signed integral conversions) do not produce undefined behavior. Instead they produce implementation-defined results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general case it is not correct to say that the pattern is the same, if the range of `signed char` does not cover `240`. If `240` is out of range, the result of this overflowing initialization  is implementation-defined (and may result in a signal, see 6.3.1.3/3). The same applies to `char` initialization if it is signed.

The language guarantees matching representations only for the common part of the ranges of `signed char` and `unsigned char`. E.g. this is guaranteed to produce the same pattern

```
char c = 10;
unsigned char c = 10;
signed char c = 10;
```

With `240` there's no such guarantee in general case (assuming it is out of range).

Comment: Just wondering, where does the standard mention what happens with `signed char c = 240;`?

Comment: @chris: In `6.3 Conversions -> 6.3.1.3 Signed and unsigned integers`: `6.3.1.3/3` Otherwise, the new type is signed and the value cannot be represented in it; either the result is implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised.

Comment: Thanks, I still can't seem to find anything about it in the C++11 standard :/ It seems the whole part you posted was nuked or completely reworded.

Comment: @chris: Oh, I was actually referring to C standard (C99). In C++11 that would be 4.7/3

Comment: Although I am sure you are right for all practical purposes, looking at §3.9/4 and §3.9.1/1 (C++11), I wonder: a) While the OP uses the word _object representation_, isn't what we need to find out about the _value representation_? b) Does the Standard really guarantee that the value representation is the same for char/signed char/unsigned char? Btw I think the C99 quotes from the comment above should be part of the answer as well.

Comment: Oh, that makes more sense than me jumping to a C++03 standard conclusion. I didn't realize the question was dually-tagged.