# Count characters in UTF8 when plain char is unsigned

Tags: c, unsigned-char

In UTF8 I use to count characters (not bytes) using this function:

```
int schars(const char *s)
{
    int i = 0;

    while (*s) {
        if ((*s & 0xc0) != 0x80) i++;
        s++;
    }
    return i;
}
```

Does this work on implementations where plain `char` is `unsigned char`?

Comment: Fun, barely related, facts: plain `char` *is* `unsigned char` under gcc by default.  Under MSVC, it's `signed char`. By the standard, `char`, `unsigned char`, and `signed char` are three distinct types.

Comment: @Corbin I think that plain `char` is `signed char` on gcc

Comment: Could have sworn that gcc has it as signed by default, but looks like you're right.  Whoops :).

Comment: This is because the default `char` type has implementation-defined signedness, unlike all the other integer types like `int`, which are all guaranteed to be signed by default.

Comment: @Corbin, David: for GCC the "default if you don't specify `-fsigned-char` or `-funsigned-char`" depends on the target. When you come to configure GCC for a new target it might be that there's a "default for the default" if you don't configure anything. I don't know.

Comment: @SteveJessop wow, I did not know this, that mean that I can force gcc to have a particular type?

Comment: @DavidRF: yes, although it also varies by target what happens if you make a choice that conflicts with the target's ABI. In principle you might see strange things happen when you call a function in a dll that takes a `char` parameter, since the caller and callee don't agree what the possible values of `char` are. In practice I'd guess that most targets will in effect just convert/reinterpret the value in the expected way.

Comment: @SteveJessop Ah, good to know. For some reason had assumed that it was purely the compiler's choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should.

You are only using binary operators and those function the same irrespective of whether the underlying data type is signed or unsigned. The only exception may be the `!=` operator, but you could replace this with a `&` and then embrace the whole thing with a `!`, ala:

```
!((*s & 0xc0) & 0x80)
```

and then you have solely binary operators.

You can verify that the characters are promoted to integers by checking section 3.3.10 of the [ANSI C Standard](http://flash-gordon.me.uk/ansi.c.txt) which states that "Each of the operands [of the bitwise AND] shall have integral type."

**EDIT**

I amend my answer. Bitwise operations are not the same on signed as on unsigned, as per 3.3 of the ANSI C Standard:

> Some operators (the unary operator ~ , and the binary operators << , >> , & , ^ , and | ,
>   collectively described as bitwise operators )shall have operands that have integral type. 
>   These operators return
>   values that depend on the internal representations of integers, and
>   thus have **implementation-defined aspects** for signed types.

In fact, performing bitwise operations on signed integers is listed as a possible security hole [here](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/INT13-C.+Use+bitwise+operators+only+on+unsigned+operands).

In the Visual Studio compiler signed and unsigned are treated the same (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dxda59dh.aspx)).

As [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8385824/bytewise-reading-of-memory-signed-char-vs-unsigned-char) discusses, it is better to use `unsigned char` to do byte-wise reads of memory and manipulations of memory.

Comment: Thanks Richard, that's what I thought

Comment: @DavidRF, I've continued to think about the problem and now I am less sure of my answer. If you were reading into `unsigned char` everything would be good. As it is, I am not sure of what happens when you perform `&` on a `signed char`. I'm trying to figure out how to do a safe conversion.

Comment: yes, "Ramón" returns 4 instead of 5 using `!((*s & 0xc0) & 0x80)`, thanks for the advise

Comment: @DavidRF, I tried rephrasing the question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14233716/bitwise-and-on-signed-chars) - hopefully some of the answers there will put this to rest.

Answer (score 3):

It works as well when `char` is unsigned as it does when it's signed.

In both a signed 2's complement representation and in an unsigned representation, the 8th and 7th bits of a UTF8 code unit are `10` if and only if the code unit is *not* the first code unit of a code point. So you're counting 1 for the first code unit of each code point.

`int` is not guaranteed to be a large enough type to contain the number of characters in every string, but I assume you don't care ;-)

"Character" is potentially an ambiguous term. This code counts Unicode code points, which is not the same thing as displayable characters ("graphemes"). Sometimes multiple code points represent a single grapheme, for example when combining marks are used for accents. About the only practical use for knowing how many code points there are in a Unicode string, is to calculate how many bytes it will occupy when encoded as UTF-32. If you're careful, you can ensure that the only code that needs to process "characters" is the font engine, plus some complex operations like Unicode normalization and character encodings.

Comment: Thanks Steve, yes, size_t is a better option but I use `int` to avoid casts on every call

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will.

`*s` will be promoted to `int` before the computations take place. So, your code is equivalent to:

```
if (((int) *s & 0xC0) != 0x80) i++;
```

And the above will work even if `char` is unsigned.

Comment: Strictly speaking, the literals 0xC0 and 0x80 are already of type `int`, so the only promotion taking place is the one where *s is converted to int.

Comment: @Lundin, you're right, there are no `char` literals. Answer updated accordingly, thanks :)

Comment: (In C++ they would be of type char, however)

Comment: @Lundin: in C++, `0xC0` and `0x80` have type `int` the same as C. The difference in C++ is that `'a'` has type `char`, whereas in C it has type `int`.

Comment: Yup, `'\xC0'` would be `char`, but plain `0xC0` is `int`.

Comment: Ah yeah that's correct, for some reason I mixed it up with character literals. Hex literals are of course of type int :)