# Bitwise AND on signed chars

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I have a file that I've read into an array of data type `signed char`. I cannot change this fact.

I would now like to do this: `!((c[i] & 0xc0) & 0x80)` where `c[i]` is one of the signed characters.

Now, I know from section 6.5.10 of the [C99 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) that "Each of the operands [of the bitwise AND] shall have integral type."

And Section 6.5 of the C99 specification tells me:

> Some operators (the unary operator ~ , and the binary operators << , >> , & , ^ , and | ,
>   collectively described as bitwise operators )shall have operands that have integral type. 
>   These operators return
>   values that depend on the internal representations of integers, and
>   thus have **implementation-defined aspects** for signed types.

My question is two-fold:

- Since I want to work with the original bit patterns from the file, how can I convert/cast my `signed char` to `unsigned char` so that the bit patterns remain unchanged?
- Is there a list of these "implementation-defined aspects" anywhere (say for MVSC and GCC)?

Or you could take a different route and argue that this produces the same result for both signed and unsigned chars for any value of `c[i]`.

Naturally, I will reward references to relevant standards or authoritative texts and discourage "informed" speculation.

Comment: Not quoting standards or anything, but don't you answer your own question here? "how can I convert/cast" <-- how do you see a cast failing?

Comment: @fge, I am not sure if it is guaranteed to succeed.

Comment: @Richard If you typecast then bit patterns can't be remain unchanged.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan I am doubtful about this... At least on my environment, doing `char x = 0xff;` and printing out `(unsigned char) x` prints out 255, not -1

Comment: Please note that `!((c[i] & 0xc0) & 0x80)` is equivalent to `!(c[i] & 0x80)`, there's no point in doing two and:s.

Comment: Fair enough, @GrijeshChauhan, my goal is to find a way to manipulate `c[i]` such that `!((c[i] & 0xc0) & 0x80)` will return the same result regardless of whether the original `c[i]` was signed or unsigned.

Comment: I'm not a language lawyer type, but IIRC conversion from a signed to unsigned type is well defined (it is defined, I think, as adding INT_MAX+1 to make the result positive, and as unsigned values wrap, everything works as expected).

Comment: @Richard Did you tried with `!((c[i] & 0xc0) & 0x80)` where `c[i]` is signed , or your conceptually says it will produce wrong result. Yes its not portable as you mention ANSI `3.3.10 of the ANSI C Standard` **EDIT** comment and its what `JasonD` answer says! check that section too

Comment: About the "implementation-defined aspects" part: I think this is to leave room for arbitrary number representations, especially of [signed numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations). I think most compilers use the most convenient representation available on the target machine, so you don't have to worry that the "big" compilers will encode numbers in a different way than two's complement when targeting x86. Just don't expect it to run identically on machines that use other number representations (although modern examples are scarce).

Comment: The raw bit representation of the source is copied verbatim, and it is re-interpreted according to the destination type. This can also be achieved via [**aliasing**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing_%28computing%29)

Comment: @fge you were correct bit pattern for char(128) == char(-128) for one byte is same...I was wrong

Answer (score 5):

As others point out, in all likelyhood your implementation is based on two's complement, and will give exactly the result you expect.

However, if you're worried about the results of an operation involving a signed value, and all you care about is the bit pattern, simply cast directly to an equivalent unsigned type. The results are defined under the standard:

---

### 6.3.1.3 Signed and unsigned integers

1. ...
2. Otherwise, if the new type is unsigned, the value is converted by repeatedly adding or
   subtracting one more than the maximum value that can be represented in the new type
   until the value is in the range of the new type.

---

This is essentially specifying that the result will be the two's complement representation of the value.

Fundamental to this is that in two's complement maths the result of a calculation is modulo some power of two (i.e. the number of bits in the type), which in turn is exactly equivalent to masking off the relevant number of bits. And the complement of a number is the number subtracted from the power of two.

Thus adding a negative value is the same as adding any value which differs from the value by a multiple of that power of two.

i.e:

```
        (0 + signed_value) mod (2^N)
==
      (2^N + signed_value) mod (2^N)
==
  (7 * 2^N + signed_value) mod (2^N)
```

etc. (if you know modulo, that should be pretty self-evidently true)

So if you have a negative number, adding a power of two will make it positive (-5 + 256 = 251), but the bottom 'N' bits will be exactly the same (0b11111011) and it will not affect the outcome of a mathematical operation. As values are then truncated to fit the type, the result is exactly the binary value you expected with even if the result 'overflows' (i.e. what you might think happens if the number was positive to start with - this wrapping is also well defined behaviour).

So in 8-bit two's complement:

- -5 is the same as 251 (i.e 256 - 5) - 0b11111011
- If you add 30, and 251, you get 281. But that's larger than 256, and 281 mod 256 equals 25. Exactly the same as 30 - 5.
- 251 * 2 = 502. 502 mod 256 = 246. 246 and -10 are both 0b11110110.

Likewise if you have:

```
unsigned int a;
int b;

a - b == a + (unsigned int) -b;
```

Under the hood, this cast is unlikely to be implemented with arithmetic and will certainly be a straight assignment from one register/value to another, or just optimised out altogether as the maths does not make a distinction between signed and unsigned (intepretation of CPU flags is another matter, but that's an implementation detail). The standard exists to ensure that an implementation doesn't take it upon itself to do something strange instead, or I suppose, for some weird architecture which isn't using two's complement...

Comment: I am not sure , if you examples bit more then it would be quit helpful..it seem to me, you answered the problem..

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan No, it doesn't. (the maths on unsigned types is defined as being 2's complement without any overflow problems - i.e. it wraps, so the result of all this is that the 'bit-pattern' will be unchanged)

Comment: Yes your are correct this code `char c =-128; printf("%d %d\n",(unsigned char)c, c);` prints `128 -128` and bit patterns for `char(128)==char(-128)` are same for 1 byte. good answer `+1`.

Answer (score 1):

`unsigned char UC = *(unsigned char*)&C` - this is how you can convert signed `C` to unsigned keeping the "bit pattern". Thus you could change your code to something like this:

```
!(( (*(unsigned char*)(c+i)) & 0xc0) & 0x80)
```

Explanation(with references):

[761](http://c0x.coding-guidelines.com/6.3.2.3.html) *When a pointer to an object is converted to a pointer to a character type, the result points to the lowest addressed byte of the object*.

[1124](http://c0x.coding-guidelines.com/6.5.3.4.html) *When applied to an operand that has type char, unsigned char, or signed char, (or a qualified version thereof) the result is 1*.

These two implies that `unsigned char` pointer points to the same byte as original `signed char` pointer.

Comment: As per my question, @kerim, you should explain your reasoning with reference to either standards or authoritative sources. This falls in the realm of "informed" speculation.

Comment: What's not clear in my answer, @Richard? You can [convert](http://c0x.coding-guidelines.com/6.3.2.3.html) pointers, data pointed doesn't change when you do it, signed/unsigned chars are of the same size... What else you may think of?

Comment: @kerim Brother you didn't test all possible cases..And  in typecase bit pattern will be change that is sure...Think again,try again

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan - please, help me understand where I'm wrong. I just can't get out of the box, can't see the probjem here....

Comment: @kerim, it is not whether your answer is clear or not. It's whether your answer is reliable. What you've put there is black magic until you point at specific standards or references that guarantee its truth. Linking to a page helps your answer, but does little to improve it. You should amend your answer to use the relevant portions of the linked page to show why your answer is correct.

Comment: @Richard, you're right! I'm too used to this idiom so that it "just works" for me...

Comment: @kerim Ok I give you a hint that why your are wrong. do like this `char c =-128;` and print like this: `(*(unsigned char*)(&c))` print its value.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan - it gives `128`(0x80).

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan, why do you think bit pattern for `char(128)!=char(-128)`? I don't understand...sorry!

Comment: @Richard You originally cite an early draft to a withdrawn standard that has been obsolete for 23 years. So you really can't complain about others' lack of reliable sources.

Comment: @Lundin, there were originally no sources cited here. I've updated my question to reflect the C99 standard, which uses the same language.

Comment: @kerim you are correct  bit pattern for `char(128)==char(-128)` for one byte. it means on your system this also works `!((c[i] & 0xc0) & 0x80)` check.

Comment: @Lundin you are correct its old reference but know bit pattern doesn't change.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan. Also, when using this method a compiler(e.g. MSVC) optimizes it so that data doesn't even have leave registers. In comparison to the solution with arithmetic involved(which won't be optimized out).

Comment: Actually, from the language-lawyer's point of view, I believe that the various standards are quite different when it comes to binary representation of chars (6.2.6.2). Correct me if I'm wrong, but C90 and earlier were generally vague, C99 clarified that unsigned char may not contain any padding bits, and C11 added that the same applies to signed char. So quoting the right version of the standard may be relevant here, if we are to be picky.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to have something similar to:

```
signed char c[] = "\x7F\x80\xBF\xC0\xC1\xFF";

for (int i = 0; c[i] != '\0'; i++)
{
    if (!((c[i] & 0xC0) & 0x80))
        ...
}
```

You are (correctly) concerned about sign extension of the `signed char` type.  In practice, however, `(c[i] & 0xC0)` will convert the signed character to a (signed) `int`, but the `& 0xC0` will discard any set bits in the more significant bytes; the result of the expression will be in the range 0x00 .. 0xFF.  This will, I believe, apply whether you use sign-and-magnitude, one's complement or two's complement binary values.  The detailed bit pattern you get for a specific signed character value varies depending on the underlying representation; but the overall conclusion that the result will be in the range 0x00 .. 0xFF is valid.

There is an easy resolution for that concern — cast the value of `c[i]` to an `unsigned char` before using it:

```
if (!(((unsigned char)c[i] & 0xC0) & 0x80))
```

The value `c[i]` is converted to an `unsigned char` before it is promoted to an `int` (or, the compiler might promote to `int`, then coerce to `unsigned char`, then promote the `unsigned char` back to `int`), and the unsigned value is used in the `&` operations.

Of course, the code is now merely redundant.  Using `& 0xC0` followed by `& 0x80` is entirely equivalent to just `& 0x80`.

If you're processing UTF-8 data and looking for continuation bytes, the correct test is:

```
if (((unsigned char)c[i] & 0xC0) == 0x80)
```

Answer (score 0):

> "Since I want to work with the original bit patterns from the file,
>   how can I convert/cast my signed char to unsigned char so that the bit
>   patterns remain unchanged?"

As someone already explained in a previous answer to your question on the same topic, any small integer type, be it signed or unsigned, will get promoted to the type `int` whenever used in an expression.

C11 6.3.1.1

> "If an int can represent all values of the original type (as
>   restricted by the width, for a bit-field), the value is converted to
>   an int; otherwise, it is converted to an unsigned int. These are
>   called the integer promotions."

Also, as explained in the same answer, integer literals are always of the type `int`.

Therefore, your expression will boil down to the pseudo code `(int) & (int) & (int)`. The operations will be performed on three temporary int variables and the result will be of type int.

Now, if the original data contained bits that may be interpreted as sign bits for the specific signedness representation (in practice this will be two's complement on all systems), you will get problems. Because these bits will be preserved upon promotion from signed char to int.

And then the bit-wise & operator performs an AND on every single bit regardless of the contents of its integer operand (C11 6.5.10/3), be it signed or not. If you had data in the signed bits of your original signed char, it will now be lost. Because the integer literals (0xC0 or 0x80) will have no bits set that corresponds to the sign bits.

The solution is to prevent the sign bits from getting transferred to the "temporary int". One solution is to cast c[i] to unsigned char, which is completely well-defined (C11 6.3.1.3). This will tell the compiler that "the whole contents of this variable is an integer, there are no sign bits to be concerned about".

Better yet, make a habit of always using unsigned data in every form of bit manipulations. The purist, 100% safe, MISRA-C compliant way of re-writing your expression is this:

```
if ( ((uint8_t)c[i] & 0xc0u) & 0x80u) > 0u)
```

The u suffix actually enforces the expression to be of unsigned int, but it is good practice to always cast to the *intended type*. It tells the reader of the code "I actually know what I am doing and I also understand all weird implicit promotion rules in C".

And then if we know our hex, `(0xc0 & 0x80)` is pointless, it is always true. And `x & 0xC0 & 0x80` is always the same as `x & 0x80`. Therefore simplify the expression to:

```
if ( ((uint8_t)c[i] & 0x80u) > 0u)
```

---

> "Is there a list of these "implementation-defined aspects" anywhere"

Yes, the C standard conveniently lists them in Appendix J.3. The only implementation-defined aspect you encounter in this case though, is the signedness implementation of integers. Which in practice is always two's complement.

EDIT:
The quoted text in the question is concerned with that the various bit-wise operators will produce implementation-defined results. This is just briefly mentioned as implementation-defined even in the appendix with no exact references. The actual chapter 6.5 doesn't say much regarding impl.defined behavior of & | etc. The only operators where it is explicitly mentioned is the << and >>, where left shifting a negative number is even undefined behavior, but right shifting it is implementation-defined.