# How to solve typedef redefinition in C++?

Tags: c++, typedef

I imported some code into my project, but there is a line:
`typedef signed char byte;`

But the `byte` has been typedef in `rpcndr.h`. There are many codes using this type, so just changing the name is a difficult thing. I'm wondering if  there's an easy way to solve such redefinition?

P.S. My code is running on Windows and all codes do not has a namespace, so add namespaces is equal to change type name.

Comment: Maybe look into namespaces?

Comment: In my experience `byte` or `BYTE` is almost always used for an unsigned char

Comment: @MattMcNabb It is used in `unpack200`, so I do not know whether it will work if I change it into unsigned char .

Comment: Ok, so as far as I understand you have two separate libraries that both declare a byte typedef?

Comment: @marsh Yes , before the custom typedef , there is `#include <windows.h>
#include <winuser.h>`, I don't know how to manage the include to sovle redefinition.

Comment: @MattMcNabb Making it a typedef of a plain `char` allows it to be used with standard C and C++ functions that operate on raw bytes.

Comment: Are you sure you need both of those files? Try putting #define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN before your includes.

Comment: @marsh that's it ! I just forget this define ! Plz post your answer I will accept it .

Comment: Glad it worked out for you. I posted it.

Comment: @zenith there's not much point in typedefing plain `char`, just use `char`

Comment: @MattMcNabb except that it conveys the semantics better: are we working on characters, or raw memory.

Comment: @zenith I'd strongly recommend using `unsigned char` for working with raw memory, in order to avoid value transformations related to signed integers

Comment: @MattMcNabb Actually, C++ guarantees that [no such value transformations will happen with plain `char`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8386615/3425536), even if it's signed. They're only allowed on `signed char`.

Comment: @zenith I think C++11 and later force 2's complement anyway. I also was thinking of operations like `(x << 8) | y` . With unsigned char this combines two bytes; however if `y` is a negative plain `char` then that operation returns `y` because of "sign extension".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding: #define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN before your includes.

[What does #defining WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN exclude exactly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11040133/what-does-defining-win32-lean-and-mean-exclude-exactly)

Answer (score 3):

You could wrap your typedefs in namespaces.

```
namespace Foo
{
    typedef signed char byte;
}

namespace Bar
{
    typedef signed char byte;
}
```

Then use it like `Foo::byte; Bar::byte;`

[Why and how should I use namespaces in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4211827/why-and-how-should-i-use-namespaces-in-c)

Comment: It is same to change all the byte used in code to the one with namspaces.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, you do not need to namespace the other typedef if you cant modify there code. Simply typedef your own, so that you can access it with namespace::typedef